# Why do still we have the rant tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

It seems that all of the [rant](/questions/tagged/rant) questions have been ported over to MSE, but the [tag summary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/rant/info) is missing. There is one fairly recent question tagged with it however, so I suspect that the OP created the tag when formulating the question. Here's an excerpt of the wiki summary that now has a home on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/rant/info):

> First and foremost, the existence of this tag does not allow you to go
>   off and rant however you want. Ranting comes in two forms:
>   constructive and unconstructive. The latter will be swiftly closed
>   (and possibly deleted) by the community, which is why there are so few
>   questions here actually using this tag (hint hint).

I can't find any related discussion on the tag. Should the wiki summary be edited or should it be burninated?

Comment: What are you on about? The old MSO *became* MSE when the split hppened, which means the tag no longer existed here on the new MSO and had to be created. I'm a bit confused why exactly you think it needs to be destroyed though. Because it exists on MSE?